# rails Formtastic routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I am trying to setup a simple form using formtastic but running into a routing error when trying to save the form. I get the following error message. Let me know if you need any further info. I am assuming this is a simple mistake on my part that I am overlooking.

Error

```
No route matches {:controller=>"projects"}
```

new

```
<%= semantic_form_for @project do |form| %>
  <%= form.inputs %>
  <%= form.buttons %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def new
    @project = Project.new
end

def create
  @project = Project.new(params[:project])
  if @project.save
    flash[:success] = "Project Created!"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Project failed"
    redirect :action => "new"
  end
end
```

Routes

```
resources :project
```

Model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
resources :project
```

to

```
resources :projects
```

Comment: I don't think that will work since my controller is "Project" not "Projects". I could be wrong though?

Comment: you need to rename you controller too. it should be named Projects, this is rails naming conventions for controllers(name should be pluralized). File - projects_controller.rb, file contains *class ProjectsController < ApplicationController*. Routes - resources :projects.